# ioctl to detect a disc in upside direction

Tags: ioctl, cd, cd-drive

I am trying to find whether a disc is inverted in upside direction, or there is no disc.Till now I am getting NO_DISC even when I am inserting a disc in Upside direction.Please anyone tell me if there is any possible ioctl available through which I can differentiate between these two situations i.e. No_Disc and disc in upside direction.

Comment: Which OS?  This is probably not possible.  It would require the hardware to detect and then communicate this state to the driver.  I've never heard of CD hardware that could do this.  A CD laser can't focus on an upside-down disc because of the wrong focal-length.  A DVD laser can focus (there are two-sided DVDs), but it would still show no disc unless there was something printed on the back.

Comment: Thanks for replying Ryan...The OS I am using is armv71 GNU/Linux.